# How to get python interpreter full argv command line options?

Tags: python, argv, werkzeug

As we know from documentation:

> -c 
>   If this option is given, the first element of sys.argv will be "-c" and the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path (allowing modules in that directory to be imported as top level modules).

How can I get full interpreter command line options? I need it to solve this:

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/f50bdc04cf1c8d71d12d13a0c8ef2878477f4d24/werkzeug/_reloader.py#L141

If I start werkzeug development server, then it will lost `-c cmd` option on fork. I want to patch werkzeug, but cant find how to get real options.

If you want to know why I need this - I want to preexecute some code before manage.py that want to parse `sys.argv`. And also I think that werkzeug method is incorrect due it is not working in corner case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I start werkzeug development server, then it will lost -c cmd
>   option on fork.

First of all, the process is not simply forked. A fresh Python interpreter is invoked.

What do you mean with `it will lost -c cmd`? The fact that the `cmd` string is gone in argv? That is:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)"
['-c']
```

Indeed, the `cmd` string is not accessible from within `sys.argv`. [This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is related documentation:

> If the command was executed using the -c command line option to the
>   interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'

The docs do not comment on the actual command string. While that command string was clearly "sent" as an argument to the Python interpreter exectuable, the CPython implementation does not seem to expose this information within `sys.argv`. I guess there is no way to reconstruct this information without changing the source code of `sysmodule.c`. So, if you think you depend on extracting `cmd` -- you shouldn't! You need to find another way to inject this information.

**Edit:**

The actual command string is consumed in [`Modules/main.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/main.c) in function `Py_Main()`:

```
wcscpy(command, _PyOS_optarg);
```

This `command` is what is being executed later on in `main.c`.

The command line arguments are processed via `PySys_SetArgv(argc-_PyOS_optind, argv+_PyOS_optind);`, which in turn calls `makeargvobject()` in `sysmodule.c`. The latter function translates the binary argument data into Python unicode objects (at least in Python 3 it does) in a `for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {}`-like loop. So, `argc` must (purposely) be off by -1 in order to ignore the command in said loop.

That is, the magic of dropping the command argument is in setting `_PyOS_optind`, so that the subsequent call to `PySys_SetArgv(argc-_PyOS_optind, argv+_PyOS_optind);` suggests an argument count smaller (by 1) than it actually is.

I did not really follow through, but I guess the decrement in these lines is responsible:

```
if (command != NULL) {
    /* Backup _PyOS_optind and force sys.argv[0] = '-c' */
    _PyOS_optind--;
    argv[_PyOS_optind] = L"-c";
}
```

**Edit2:**

Verified the crucial role of `_PyOS_optind` here with the following patch to the current Python 3 tip:

```
diff --git a/Modules/main.c b/Modules/main.c
--- a/Modules/main.c
+++ b/Modules/main.c
@@ -679,9 +679,11 @@
     }

     if (command != NULL) {
         /* Backup _PyOS_optind and force sys.argv[0] = '-c' */
         _PyOS_optind--;
-        argv[_PyOS_optind] = L"-c";
+        _PyOS_optind = 0;
+        //argv[_PyOS_optind] = L"-c";
     }

     if (module != NULL) {
```

Test:

```
 $ ./python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)"
['./python', '-c', 'import sys; print(sys.argv)']
```

Comment: Thank you! Did not find where ``cmd`` really striped. And in this file I have found Py_GetArgcArgv!

And then I tried some weird staff like this with strange result:

`>>> python -c 'import ctypes; argv = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)(); argc = ctypes.c_int(); ctypes.pythonapi.Py_GetArgcArgv(ctypes.byref(argc), ctypes.byref(argv)); print([argv[i] for i in xrange(0, argc.value)])'`
`['python', '-c', '-c']`