# get the python command-line options passed to the python interpreter

Tags: python

How to programmatically retrieve the interpreter options passed to the python interpreter within that instance?

For example, given command

```
python -B -u script.py
```

**what Python code lists the passed interpreter command-line options `-B` and `-u`?**

I could query `sys.dont_write_bytecode` to infer that command-line option `-B` was passed.  But I want Python code that is generic to any interpreter option.  I imagine a code snippet that would return a list of command-line options the interpreter was given, e.g. `[ '-B', '-u' ]`.

To question reviewers, this question is not answered in [How to get python interpreter full argv command line options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412903/how-to-get-python-interpreter-full-argv-command-line-options).  That answer for that question suggests changing the C-runtime code of the interpreter and recompiling Python.  That is not a suitable solution for my needs.

Comment: You may need to use argparse.

Comment: @Hiadore can you be more specific - which function in `argparse`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get python interpreter full argv command line options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412903/how-to-get-python-interpreter-full-argv-command-line-options)

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914236/5588279

Comment: Btw, I want to point out that this an implementation-specific problem. So the solution won't work on the others other than C implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the command line arguments of the Python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336431/retrieve-the-command-line-arguments-of-the-python-interpreter)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sys.argv

example:

```
C:\Users\Rick>python -c "from sys import argv;print(argv)"
['-c']
```